# how to prevent c# XmlElement.SetAttribute change '&' to '&amp;'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to get a xml tag like:

```
    <link url="http://www.xxx.com/?&q=xxx">xxx</link>
```

but the `SetAttribute` method changes `&` to `&amp;`, how can I prevent that?

my code:

```
    XmlElement Link = doc.CreateElement("Link");
    Link2.SetAttribute("url", "http://www.xxx.com/?&q=xxxx");
```

please help me ! thanks!

Comment: You cannot prevent that because if you did the result would not be XML. It should not matter anyway, because when the XML is parsed `&amp;` will be converted transparently back to `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=XML#Escaping) wiki article to see other characters that also have to be escaped. It also describes why.